# django smart-select security issue

Tags: python, django

I have implemented django smart-select successfully, but it has problem with security. The endpoint is readable without any permissions. I also found a warning from smart-select document but I don't know how to use django-autocomplete-light. Does django-autocomplete-light support the same feature with smart-select? Is there anybody know how to fix this security issue.

Warning: The AJAX endpoint enforces no permissions by default. This means that any model with a chained field will be world readable. If you would like more control over this permission, the django-autocomplete-light package is a great, high-quality package that enables the same functionality with permission checks.